# Issue found: Less broad app-visibility method should be used

Tags: android, google-play

After publish in play store they reviewed our app they sent [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLFaD.png) to my mail id.
Can you help on this?

Comment: You need to give us more info-  what are you using the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission for?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's asking about this permission. Why are you using it?
There are common uses

1. Open URLs in a browser or other app.
2. Check if a browser is available.
3. Open URLs in Custom Tabs.
4. Let non-browser apps handle URLs.

[For more detail follow this link](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases)